# What does docker use for (image) versioning?

Tags: git, docker

I am curious. It looks like git to me, but I can't find sources that confirm that. Or does it have it's own revision control system ?

Comment: image versioning or `Dockerfile` versioning? Or your question about docker registry server for image versioning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker doesn't internally use git today for any kind of resource versioning. It does however:

- Rely on hashing to uniquely identify the file system layers: this is what can make it resemble git to the user
- Take initial inspiration in the notion of [commit](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#commit), [pushes](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#push) and [pulls](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#pull)

One thing that makes this super obvious is the `docker history` command that will show you all successive "commits" (i.e., operations) that make up the image, each with an individual hash:

```
$ docker history dev
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                         COMMENT
437e07e119e1        11 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:3c72cf7559b6aeff6b   80.23 MB                     
92b739339069        7 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENTRYPOINT &{["hack/dind"]}   0 B                          
07ed6f8a66d7        7 hours ago         /bin/sh -c set -x     && git clone https://gi   4.462 MB                     
0a7eacf986e3        7 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV RSRC_COMMIT=e48dbf1b7fc   0 B                          
41478ca01b73        7 hours ago         /bin/sh -c set -x                               && export GOPATH="$(mktemp   2.689 MB            
070d4d30261e        7 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV TOMLV_COMMIT=9baf8a8a9f   0 B                          
e75c29475d7a        7 hours ago         /bin/sh -c set -x                               && export GOPATH="$(mktemp   3.227 MB            
857a0ec21751        7 hours ago         /bin/sh -c ./contrib/download-frozen-image.sh   3.59 MB                      
e936f5546782        7 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:5d664ff5e9669851c   3.866 kB                     
0d12674bd0af        7 hours ago         /bin/sh -c ln -sv $PWD/contrib/completion/bas   0 B                          
ef858f6d9027        7 hours ago         /bin/sh -c ln -sfv $PWD/.bashrc ~/.bashrc       0 B                          
287721a0a2b6        7 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV DOCKER_BUILDTAGS=apparm   0 B
```

One final thing to note is that Docker is moving toward content-addressable layers, so those hash are not randomly generated (<strike>like git does</strike>) but uniquely identify a given content.

Comment: There's no random element in the creation of Git's SHA-1 hashes. They're based on the contents of the commit, including the tree id (i.e. the contents of the files), author name, author date, committer name, committer date, and parent commit id.